# ImportError when using scipy.io

Tags: python, scipy

So I am having a bit of trouble using scipy. I have been importing data from a `.mat` file (matlab variables) and up until today it has worked perfectly. I have no idea what changed or when because I have been developing a text - based data format so that I can avoid depending on Matlab for writing my data. Anyways, I am getting a bizzare import error when I import scipy.io

```
import scipy.io
myData = scipy.io.loadmat('some_data_file')
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
>>> import scipy.io
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\pyzo2014a\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\__init__.py", line 85, in <module>
    from .matlab import loadmat, savemat, whosmat, byteordercodes
  File "C:\pyzo2014a\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .mio import loadmat, savemat, whosmat
  File "C:\pyzo2014a\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\mio.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .mio4 import MatFile4Reader, MatFile4Writer
  File "C:\pyzo2014a\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\mio4.py", line 11, in <module>
    import scipy.sparse
  File "C:\pyzo2014a\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\__init__.py", line 217, in <module>
    from .csgraph import cs_graph_components
  File "C:\pyzo2014a\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\csgraph\__init__.py", line 148, in <module>
    from ._shortest_path import shortest_path, floyd_warshall, dijkstra,\
ImportError: No module named 'scipy.sparse.csgraph._shortest_path'
```

I thought there might be something wrong with my python distribution so I reinstalled it, however the problem persists, and now the installer says it can't find '_shortest_path.py' when it is installing. When I navigate to `.../Libs/site-packages/scipy/sparse/csgraph/` I find that indeed there is no module named `_shortest_path`. I don't understand how this error came about or how anything in my code would change it. Has anyone else come across this problem?

I am using [Pyzo 2014](http://www.pyzo.org/) on Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restore shortest_path.pyd in your virust chest
http://www.blendernation.com/2014/06/28/getting-a-virus-warning-with-blender-2-71-heres-why/